# Unable to cast object of type 'System.EventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs?

Tags: vb.net, listview

Had this working before, now it stopped. Basically needs to open the item that was double clicked. DirrList is the path to the folder that ListView1 displays.

Where am I going wrong?

```
    Private Sub ListView1_MouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    Dim lvi As ListViewItem = ListView1.HitTest(e.Location).Item
    ' MsgBox(lvi)
    If lvi IsNot Nothing Then
        '  MsgBox(lvi)
        Process.Start(DirrList & "\" & lvi.SubItems(0).Text)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Windows Form Application

Comment: You mixed and matched `MouseDoubleClick` and `DoubleClick`.  Your Handles indicates the latter but that takes `EventArgs`.  Dont type in your own event handlers, let VS create them

Comment: _Handles ListView1.MouseDoubleClick_

Comment: @Steve this worked, thanks!